# Rails 4 - Nested Resources, I think

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a REQUEST model that routes to 3 USERS for approvals.  REQUEST has approver1_id, approver2_id and approver3_id (which are all USERS).  What is the best way to handle this association?

in the REQUEST model, do I just do:

```
belongs_to :approver1, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'approver1_id'
belongs_to :approver2, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'approver2_id'
belongs_to :approver3, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'approver3_id'
```

and in the USER model:

```
has_many :requests
```

Or do I do some sort of nested resource in ROUTES?  Or...?

Comment: if you want to use the belongs_to relationship then you should naturally have some constraint on the model that is on the receiving end of the relationship. Since you are wanting a one-to-many relationship you will want to use the has_many in your user model. If you don't do this getting access to all requests for the user won't be as simple as users.requests

Comment: Ok, I already have `has_many :requests` in the USER model, so is this the best way to handle what I'm trying to accomplish?  Just wanna be sure I'm using best practice... Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to call model Request. It may collide at some point with method in controllers.